# Dictionary.app forgetting custom labels

Tags: dictionary

Long story short when Apple moved from Leopard to Snow Leopard they changed their Japanese dictionary provider and along the way lost access to some very useful tools (e.g. a Japanese thesaurus), so I've been importing them into every new installation of OS X ever since.

For a few versions it had no problem letting me re-label the dictionaries (right click, "Edit Label") so I could tell which was which, but for a while now it's been forgetting the labels when the app gets closed (resulting in my dictionary bar looking something like: Japanese, Japanese, Japanese-English, Japanese-English, Japanese Synonyms).

I decided to try editing labels again and seeing if Big Sur solved any of this.  The current dictionaries remember their names, but the imported ones revert their labels as soon as the app is closed.  I've tried updating the info.plist file inside each dictionary's file to change references that look like the default label to what I want it to be, but it hasn't changed the behavior inside the app.

Is there anything I can check on that would fix this behavior?